# How to prove the following identity of fermion creation and annihilation operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, fermions, anticommutator

Define $$M_{\theta} \equiv \exp\left[\theta \sum_s \left(d^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s)b(\vec{p},s) -b^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s)d(\vec{p},s)\right)\right],$$ where $\theta$ is a continuous real parameter. Show via differentiation with respect to $\theta$ that

$$M_{\theta}b^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s)M_{\theta}^{\dagger} = \cos\theta b^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s) + \sin\theta d^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s)$$

$$ M_{\theta}d^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s)M_{\theta}^{\dagger} = -\sin\theta b^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s) + \cos\theta d^{\dagger}(\vec{p},s)$$

where we have $$\{b(\vec{p},s,t),b^{\dagger}(\vec{p}',s',t) \} = (2\pi)^3 2E_p \delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{p}')\delta_{ss'}$$ and $$\{d(\vec{p},s,t),d^{\dagger}(\vec{p}',s',t) \} = (2\pi)^3 2E_p \delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{p}')\delta_{ss'}$$ and all other anti-commutators vanish.

I tried to differentiate the left hand side of equation, and to use those anticommutators to simplify it. But the equation looks too messy to see how I can get the right hand side (with delta function etc). Can anyone show me what I am missing?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @J.Murray I have taken the derivative with respect to $\theta$, but the expression looks messy and I don't see how I can obtain the results.

Comment: You should show what you have tried and try to describe what conceptual difficulties you feel you are facing.  Otherwise, this question is not in accordance with the [homework-like question policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: @lol: you should probably take the derivative of the right hand side (RHS) of the 1. eq. I also wonder whether an imaginary i was not forgotten in the RHS of eq. 1 (check that, it is just a doubt). The anticommutator rules are there to use them to get the result (eq.2 +3). Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out how to do this problem, so I will put an answer here for my own record as well.

Basically, after differentiate the $M_{\theta}b^{\dagger}M_{\theta}^{\dagger}$, we get $M_{\theta}[\sum_{s'}(d^{\dagger}b-b^{\dagger}d),b^{\dagger}] M_{\theta}^{\dagger}$. The commutator equals $d^{\dagger}$ after doing integration. Then we have $M_{\theta}[\sum_{s'}(d^{\dagger}b-b^{\dagger}d),b^{\dagger}] M_{\theta}^{\dagger} =M_{\theta}d^{\dagger}M_{\theta}^{\dagger} $. Then take the derivative of $M_{\theta}d^{\dagger}M_{\theta}^{\dagger}$, we will get $-M_{\theta}b^{\dagger}M_{\theta}^{\dagger} $, thus we get a differential equation $\frac{d}{d\theta} (M_{\theta}b^{\dagger}M_{\theta}^{\dagger} )=-M_{\theta}b^{\dagger}M_{\theta}^{\dagger}$, which can be solved easily. Then plug in initial condition (when $\theta=0$), we can get the desired results.